# How to eliminate entity view's duplicate values?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I created a custom view for an entity. But it contains duplicate column values.

How can I show only unique values like SQL Distinct?

[image]

UPDATE:
By default, CRM consider checks for distinct record based on entire row(displayed) not just column.

Comment: Updated with screenshot.

Comment: They are duplicate records in crm database..

Comment: they are not, cases can be reported by multiple people.

Comment: if you go to student view then distinct student names will be there. in cases student can be in multiple cases.

Comment: I need to see unique students who have cases. So either solutions don't work.

Comment: then build PowerBI reports and embed it

Comment: even if you create exact duplicate records, they will be listed in view records (rows) as they meant to show them (transaction records). If you want to remove dupes then you have to build your own list

Answer (score 0):

I can try my best to answer you. You have to understand these are not exact duplicates, unless you wanted to show the cases under each student - if that's what you meant.

If you use editable grid, then you will get grouping option. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2017/01/30/dynamics-365-new-feature-editable-grids/)

[image]

Otherwise you have to merge duplicate cases or enable duplicate detection to avoid in first place.

**Update**:

Looks like a reporting requirement, so probably FetchXML SSRS report or PowerBI report can be developed and embedded in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Entity show duplicated values (using views) if the first not null column value is repeated. By default Entity use this first not null column as Primary Key. So if this column has duplicated values it will show the first record duplicated as many times as the Primary key value exists on the view.
**Solution**: ***edit this view on Entity and change the primary key to a unique column value.*** :)